# Interpretation of $l_p$ norm inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, geometric-interpretation, robust-statistics

If $1\le p\le q\le \infty$, we know that the following inequality holds:

$$\|a\|_q\le \|a\|_p.$$

What could be a possible interpretation of this inequality for a non-mathematician? For example, can we say something like "the $l_p$ norm becomes more robust (or sensitive) to outlying values with the increase of $p$"?

Comment: Note that this is not true if you are referring to $L^p$ (with capital $L$; ie for real-valued functions); it is only true with $l^p$ (with lowercase $l$; ie for say sequences).

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $\lVert a\rVert_q\leqslant \lVert a\rVert_p$ means that if $\lVert a\rVert_p\leqslant 1$, then $\lVert a\rVert_q\leqslant 1$ or in other words, that the unit ball for the $\ell^p$-norm is contained in the unit ball for the $\ell^q$-norm.

For an interpretation of the unit ball of these spaces, you can [have a look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520002/unit-ball-with-p-norm).